# Каково происхождение слова "ветхий"?

Tags: этимология

У Шанского есть статья на эту тему.

Он считает, что корень у слова *ветхий* имеет и.-е. характер: **др.-инд. vatsas** (к которому и восходит прилагательное ветхий) переводится **как «год»; лат. vetus — старый.**

Существует **диалектное слово *ветошь*** — прошлогодняя трава.

Но с каким начальным значением и когда это слово появилось в русском языке? (У Черных нет разбора этого слова).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этимологический словарь Шапошникова говорит:

> **Ветхий** — разрушающийся или пришедший в негодность от времени, от
>   употребления, обветшалый; немощный и слабый от старости, дряхлый.
>   В русском языке с XI—XVII вв. Из праслав. *ветъхъ(йь), восходящего к
>   и.-е. *wet-us-, *wetusos «годовой, годовалый, прошлогодний»,
>   производному от *wetos «год».

Также приводится упомянутое в вопросе соответствие с др.-инд. и др. языками.

В [словаре русского языка XVIII в.](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/) упоминаются помимо указанных следующие значения слова **ветхий**: существующий с давних времён, старинный (любопытные примеры употребления: ветхий стиль [календаря]; Ветхий Рим [Древний Рим]); Ветхий деньми — наименование бога.

Кстати, в русском языке есть (и почти всегда было) обычное слово **ветошь** — старое тряпьё (вторсырьё) и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, с чего вы взяли, что ветхий восходит к др.-инд. Обратите внимание, что это не так; они просто родственны.

«Русский этимологический словарь» А. Е. Аникина:

> Из прасл. *vetъxъ(jь)
>   ‘cтарый, ветхий (обычно о предметах)’, ‘ущербный (о луне)’ <
>   б.-слав. *u̯etuša- (Traut.: 356; Derks. 2008: 517). Исходное знач.,
>   видимо, ‘прошлогодний’ (ср. вéтошь°) < ‘годовалый’, ср. и.-е.
>   *u̯et- ‘год’ (о знач. см. Лар. 1977: 36; Меркулова Совр. рус. гов.
>   1991: 178).

Ветошь 'ветхое, изношенное платье; тряпье (МАС)' вполне себе литературное слово. В значении 'пожухлая трава' — диалектное.

Вопрос *когда* применительно к словам индоевропейской природы в русском языке некорректен: они были с самого начала.